# Is there a PDF software that allows printing a comment summary?

Tags: pdf

Ubuntu discourages the installation of Adobe Reader (no longer supported). Adobe Reader X allows to create (and print) a comment summary: the comments in a page are listed and referenced in a separate page (https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-comments-acrobat-reader.html#main_Print_a_comment_summary).

I am using Master PDF Editor to comment PDF documents but the comment summary feature is not available; is there any software that allows creating comment summaries?

Comment: I use Gimp, but it saves the content as a PDF image. I have tried to install the latest Adobe reader in Wine, but without success. However there are some folks who have got it right.